# Can AppleTV be used to display web page on TV?

Tags: appletv

We work inside an open space in computing, and we need to display 3 critical webpage (fullscreen mode) on 2 televisions (= 2 apple tv).

I was wondering if the apple TV's:

- can it be controlled via my macbookpro (end 2013) to browse and display another page quickly (from tab to tab). 
  I need to display 3 webpage in fullscreen for only 2 television, so I will need to change tabs few times a day and I don't want to physically go to the TV each time.
- Can the apple TV change from tab to tabs inside the browser each X minutes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no web browser for the AppleTV as of today; perhaps this will be added as an app for the 4th generation model?

That being said, the only way that I'm aware of displaying web browser contents in the device is to use AirPlay mirroring. From what I understand, any Mac produced since ~2011 should have this ability as long as it is of the Core i5/i7 ilk (the Core 2 Duos can't do this natively).

There is no way for the Apple TV *itself* to control Safari or any other apps on your MacBook Pro, however there may be an app that could do that for you, I'd check the Mac App Store.